# Flattening 2d array in javascript

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, 2d

Say i have a 2d array and i want to and i want to search for the occurence of the value int 3
I tried flattening the array and i'm assuming the time complexity is O(parentArraySize * subArraysSize)
is there any way i can make it better i don't care about space, are there any algorithm or data strutures i could use
Note: sub array size is not constant it can be bigger or smaller than 3

```
    let twoDArray = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 7], [3, 9, 10]];
    let flattenArray = [];
    for(let subAray of twoDArray){
        for(let num of subAray){
            flattenArray.push(num)
        }
    }
```

I've also tried implementing a binary search for the target value but it's only efficient for look for a single value not all possible targets

Comment: So are you looking to find all the occurrences of a number(3 in your example) or you're just concerned about searching the value(`3` in your case) in 2D array. Also will the subarrays be sorted always?

Comment: Please provide more context on what the real need is here. What is the expected output? Why is this a 2D array and not some other data structure? Is the data changing over time (between look ups), or is it fixed? In your example the flattened array is sorted: is this coincidence or is that guaranteed? Are the subarrays sorted? Why do you say binary search is only efficient for looking up a single value? Please provide an example scenario (concrete!) where it is not efficient.

Comment: @mandy8055 Yes i'm concern about searching the value 3 which will be a variable. No the subbarray will not be sorted always.

Comment: @trincot the expected output should be that I returned all subarrays which contains   the target value which in this case is 3. Expected output: [[1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 7], [3, 9, 10]] since they all contains 3. if one of them didn't contain 3 then it would'nt be included in the output. No the subarrays wont be sorted. 
In the binary search i'd have to slice and use includes which are both linear. I've check another approach use two binary searches and include all sub arrays whithin that range

Comment: If your subarrays are not sorted, there is no use for binary search. `includes` is not binary search. Can you include your code with which you produce the intended output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding each value individually, you could concatenate each nested array which should make it slighly quicker.

```
let twoDArray = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 7], [3, 9, 10]];
let flattenedArray = [];
for(let subAray of twoDArray){
    flattenedArray = flattenedArray.concat(subAray)
}
```

Comment: isn't concat linear i was looking for something along the lines of O(n), or lgn or even n * lgn for the overall algorithm